# How to both fade and slide jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this written, but the animations are colliding.
How to changes this to work correctly?

```
 function () { 
$("#presentState").show("slide", { duration: 1500, easing: 'easeOutBack', direction: directionActive }); 
$("#presentState").fadeIn( 1500,  'easeOutBack'); 
}
```

I also have tried this and it doesn't work at all.

```
 $("#presentState").show("slide", { duration: 1500, easing: 'easeOutBack', direction: directionActive }).fadeIn(1500, 'easeOutBack').dequeue();
```

Comment: What do you mean *work correctly*, chained? fade after slide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I have ended up doing:

```
function () {
$("#presentState").show("slide", { duration: 1500, easing: 'easeOutBack', direction: directionActive }).hide(); 
$("#presentState").fadeIn(1500).dequeue(); 
}
```

I had to use `.hide();` at the end of the first function call.

Answer (score 4):

You can animate multiple CSS properties by sending a property map to *[animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)*:

Hide:

```
$("#presentState").animate({ marginLeft: "-1000px", opacity: 0 }, 1500);
```

Show:

```
$("#presentState").animate({ marginLeft: "0", opacity: 1 }, 1500);
```

Comment: @RegisteredUser I checked the source (jquery.effects.slide.js) to see what *slide* does-- it turns out they create a wrapper around what you want to animate (with *overflow* set to *hidden*), then animate the *left* or *top* property.  So it should be possible to duplicate this ...

Comment: Setting opacity to 0 or 1 is not the same as show() and hide(), since this also sets the element's display to hidden or visible. Setting opacity can also conflict with using show or hide if you're not careful. For example, calling show() on an element with opacity 0, will NOT show the element.

Answer (score 0):

this is my first reply in stackoverflow and I'm hoping for agreements from you,thanks~

I have add 2 more effects based on jquery UI effect, they are slideFadein and slideFadeout You can image what the effect is like from the name: slide and fade in/out at the same time. The usage is just similar as other effects:

```
//this will slide up and fade out the element
$("#effect").effect("slideFadein",{},500);

//this will remove the element after effect end
$("#effect").effect("slideFadein",{mode:'remove'},duration);
```

jquery UI effect: [jqueryui.com/effect](http://jqueryui.com/effect)

jsFiddle:[jsfiddle.net/rw42S](http://jsfiddle.net/rw42S)

You can use these two effects by save below code in a javascript file and include after jquery.ui.js or just paste them into jquery.ui.js

Here is my code:

```
(function( $, undefined ) {
    $.effects.effect.slideFadeout = function(o,done){
        // create element
        var el = $( this ),
            props = [ "width" , "height" , "opacity"],
            speed = o.duration || 500,
            // 'hide' or 'remove'
            mode = o.mode || 'hide',
            animation,wrapper;

        // save properties
        $.effects.save( el, props );

        animation = {
            height: "0px",
            opacity: "0"
        };

        // create wrapper
        wrapper = $.effects.createWrapper( el ).css({
            overflow: "hidden"
        });

        // animate
        wrapper.animate(animation,speed,'swing',function(){
            if(el[mode]) el[mode]();
            // restore properties
            if(mode == 'hide') $.effects.restore( el, props );
            // remove wrapper
            $.effects.removeWrapper( el );
            // callback
            done();
        });
    };

    $.effects.effect.slideFadein = function(o,done){
        // create element
        var el = $( this ),
            speed = o.duration || 5000,
            props = [ "height" , "opacity"],
            animation,wrapper;

        animation = {
            height: el.outerHeight(true) + "px",
            opacity: "1"
        };

        // save properties
        $.effects.save( el, props );

        // show element to get correct width(if the element has no width)
        el.css({ height: "0px" }).show();

        // create wrapper
        wrapper = $.effects.createWrapper( el ).css({
            overflow: "hidden",
            opacity: "0",
            height: "0px"
        });

        // restore properties
        $.effects.restore( el, props );

        // animate
        wrapper.animate(animation,speed,'swing',function(){
            // remove wrapper
            $.effects.removeWrapper( el );
            // callback
            done();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question

Comment: This effect can do slide and fade simultaneously, it's an extention for jquery ui